# Google Maps Geocoding No Longer Free?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

It's been a while since I've played around with geocoding, but going through their documentation it seems to me that Google now charges $0.005 for each geocoding call. Do they no longer allow the 2,500 free requests/day? I'm in Canada if that makes a difference (the documentation listed the prices for Canada, Brazil, and India... not sure if its different in the states)... or am I missing something? I have a list of about 4,500 addresses that I need to geocode to put on a map. I'm also using PHP to make the calls to the javascript API.

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps APIs are no longer available without API keys. Additionally, you must supply credit card information before you can access their API at all. Judging by your usage, you may be able to fall within their new free $200 credit per month.

You can visit the [Google Maps API pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/) to view pricing information and see if it will still work for you. If not, or you would just like to switch, another option may be [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org).

Comment: I forgot to add I also have an API key... but I haven't set up billing yet as far as I know. The account I logged in with is also my adwords account so I'm not sure if the billing is linked

Comment: @user2588317 Make sure that you have configured billing correctly. To my knowledge, you have to have a credit card on file to do so. I believe that Google Cloud has it's own billing profiles, so your Adwords profile likely isn't in use.

Comment: make sure you set a contingent. I made an accident and was billed 10 grand over night.